D3 re-assign element attributes after Mouseover event
I have a multiline chart with mouseenter, mouseleave event to highlight one line at a time, and leave it dim when mouse leaves
There are also buttons in this chart where user can choose to view a single line:

When a button is clicked, opacity is set back to "1" to disable mouse event effect. But this doesn't work, result is selected line is dim due to mouse event effect previously.
Like this:

Below are my code:
lineGraph
    .on("mouseenter",
        function(event) {
            const thisPath = d3.select(this);
            thisPath.style("opacity", 1);
            thisPath.attr("stroke-width", 2.25);
            thisPath.raise();
        }
        )
    .on("mouseleave",
        function(event){
            const thisPath = d3.select(this);
            thisPath.style("opacity", 0.25);
        }
    );

// --------------------------------------------------
// On button change, update styling
// --------------------------------------------------
d3.selectAll(".button")
    .on('click', function(event) {
        const selectedMethod = event.target.innerHTML;
        var selectedLine = d3.select("#" +selectedMethod);
        methodSelection.forEach((method, index) => {
        if (index < 1) return;
        if (selectedMethod == "All") {
            selectedLine = d3.selectAll("#" + method);
            selectedLine.attr("opacity",1);
        }
        else {
            if (method == selectedMethod) {
                selectedLine = d3.selectAll("#" +selectedMethod);
                selectedLine.attr("opacity",1);
            }
            else {
                var unselectdLine = d3.selectAll("#" + method);
                unselectdLine.attr("display", "none");
            }
        }
        })
        });

I'm unable to figure out why setting opacity = 1 doesn't work in this case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You are setting opacity using the style attribute on the mouse events and trying to override it using the opacity attribute on the button click. This approach doesn't work because the style attribute has more priority than the opacity attribute.
You can fix it by replacing selectedLine.attr("opacity",1) with selectedLine.style("opacity",1).
The click event handler code will then look like this:
d3.selectAll(".button")
    .on('click', function(event) {
        const selectedMethod = event.target.innerHTML;
        var selectedLine = d3.select("#" +selectedMethod);
        methodSelection.forEach((method, index) => {
        if (index < 1) return;
        if (selectedMethod == "All") {
            selectedLine = d3.selectAll("#" + method);
            selectedLine.style("opacity",1);
        }
        else {
            if (method == selectedMethod) {
                selectedLine = d3.selectAll("#" +selectedMethod);
                selectedLine.style("opacity",1);
            }
            else {
                var unselectdLine = d3.selectAll("#" + method);
                unselectdLine.attr("display", "none");
            }
        }
        })
        });


I tried but it didn't work: if (method == selectedMethod) {
selectedLine = d3.selectAll("#" +selectedMethod);
selectedLine.style("opactity", 1);

Did you change it in both places? If it still doesn't work, reproduce the problem in Code Sandbox, and I will help debug it there.
